# Intercept user input data for processing before sending over Internet in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I want to create a kernel module where I need to intercept all other applications' data (user inputs) going over the internet at the OS level. I couldn't find a way to do it.
Some ways that I'm looking at:

1. Intercept all user input data at the kernel block I/O layer. One issue would is that I don't want to display the processed data on display.
2. Use the POSIX socket API to intercept the data. But I'm not sure how to differentiate the user inputted data and the application-generated data.

Comment: What about using `wireshark` package? (If you have other users, consider legal implications).

Answer (score 1):

The standard Linux way to intercept a system call is with ptrace, or for a more secure method (can't be circumvented), systemtap

https://sourceware.org/systemtap/

> SystemTap provides free software (GPL) infrastructure to
> simplify the gathering of information about the running Linux system.
> This assists diagnosis of a performance or functional problem.
> SystemTap eliminates the need for the developer to go through the
> tedious and disruptive instrument, recompile, install, and reboot
> sequence that may be otherwise required to collect data.
>
> SystemTap provides a simple command line interface and scripting
> language for writing instrumentation for a live running kernel plus
> user-space applications. We are publishing samples, as well as
> enlarging the internal "tapset" script library to aid reuse and
> abstraction.
>
> Among other tracing/probing tools, SystemTap is the tool of choice for
> complex tasks that may require live analysis, programmable on-line
> response, and whole-system symbolic access. SystemTap can also handle
> simple tracing jobs.

But mostly SystemTap is used for inspection purposes (forensics, performance, monitoring).

If you really just want something more ad-hoc, then ptrace(2) and particularly tools like strace(3) are your friend.

If you're looking at how to prevent access to certain system calls, then there are different facilities for that, such as [Seccomp BPF (SECure COMPuting with filters)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.13/userspace-api/seccomp_filter.html), and more information about your use-case would be needed.

Example, in the Linux source code, there is a document regarding [fault injection](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/fault-injection/index.html). If you're wanting a security tool (eg. the anti-walware product Sophos for Linux) implements a kernel module for things like on-access virus scanning.

If you want to *modify* data in transit, and its specifically network traffic, then there are a number of other tools you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to write a virtual network driver, similar to that created when you install something like virtual box or a vpn. Use that virtual network card to send from the pc. Have that capture the data and forward onto the real hardware.

Cant think of another method to intercept the data. Monitoring of the data might be possible as Giacomo Catenazzi suggests.

Assuming good intent here, if its for debugging purposes, perhaps a Pineapple might help? (Search Pineapple WiFi)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create a kernel mode driver. However, even if you create a virtual network device, it will take time and effort to parse it. Also, without technology that can filter user input, it would be wise to incorporate a simple method, a device like a keylogger at the kernel level to send encrypted data.